# Spring 5 Binder, @InitBinder, not populating model correctly

Tags: spring-mvc

I am upgrading a Spring 2.5 web app to Spring 5.0.3.  I am using String form tags.  In my controller I have:

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder, HttpServletRequest request) {

    CapTypeEditor capTypeEditor = new CapTypeEditor(this.getDAOFactory());
    binder.registerCustomEditor(CapType.class, "order.capType.id", capTypeEditor);
}
```

I see that this is called twice (why?) on GET and twice on POST.  On GET, the request.getParameter("order.capType.id") is null, the same in POST has the correct ID.  But then in my submit() POST method, capType is not null, but it has only the id populated and not its name:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/es/orderinfo.html", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView submit(@RequestParam("id") long id,
        @ModelAttribute("command")OrderInfoBean bean, 
          BindingResult errors, ModelMap model,
          HttpServletRequest request) { 


    Order order = bean.getOrder();
    CapType ct = order.getCapType();
...
}
```

My CapType editor is never called:

```
public class CapTypeEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {

DAOFactory daoFactory;

public CapTypeEditor(DAOFactory daoFactory){
    this.daoFactory = daoFactory;       
}

public void setAsText(String text){
    if(StringUtils.isBlank(text)||StringUtils.isEmpty(text) ){
        this.setValue(null);
        return;
    }
    Long id = Long.valueOf(text);
    CapType capType = daoFactory.getCapTypeDAO().read(id);
    this.setValue(capType);
}

public String getAsText(Object value){
    if(value == null) return StringUtils.EMPTY;
    CapType capType  = (CapType)value;
    return capType.getId().toString();
}
}
```

My JSP looks like this:

```
<form:select path="order.orderType.id" tabindex="100" cssStyle="width:149px">
    <form:option value="">none</form:option>
    <form:options items="${refData.orderTypes }" itemValue="id" itemLabel="typeName" />                                 
</form:select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually my old editors registered in @InitBinder were OK.  And @minarmahmud was right about the  not having .id in the .  Once I added a proper equals and hashcode function to my hibernate mapped model classes (e.g. CapType) everything worked, both the default values on the view  HTML and the full auto mapping of my models together on POST.  So in Model CapType:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(final Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    final CapType capType = (CapType) o;
    return Objects.equals(id, capType.id) &&
    Objects.equals(typeName, capType.getTypeName());
}
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(id, typeName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are putting invalid property path while registering the custom editor. Do this:

```
binder.registerCustomEditor(CapType.class, "capType", capTypeEditor);
```

<strike>Assuming, `OrderInfoBean` contains a field `capType`.</strike>

```
binder.registerCustomEditor(CapType.class, "order.capType", capTypeEditor);
```

As `OrderInfoBean` cotnains `Order` which contains `CapType`.

And in JSP, use <strike>`capType`</strike> `order.capType` directly as bindpath.

Comment: Right, I am going to try that now... ...my Spring 2.5 App had a command class OrderInfoBean that had (a lot of properties and) an Order that had a CapType.  But no question, I am going to try what you are taking about where Order is my Model and jsp <form:select path> is just capType or capType.id....  Will follow up.

Comment: @tom If it is like OrderInfoBean -> Order -> CapType, you need to do this: `binder.registerCustomEditor(CapType.class, "order.capType", capTypeEditor);`

Comment: thanks @minarmahmud.  will try...  still ok to have JSP <form:select path="order.capType.id">?  I had to do that to get the selects to default, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53016491/spring-5-form-tags-input-select-etc-not-showing-value-from-model

Comment: @tom For property editor to work you need to do: `<form:select path="order.capType">` (without `id`)

Comment: interesting @minarmahmud.  maybe you can help me with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53016491/spring-5-form-tags-input-select-etc-not-showing-value-from-model  ...without the id, the values in the form:select's are not selected to current values in model.

Comment: according to this post https://ankeetmaini.wordpress.com/2012/08/01/binding-nested-objects-complex-properties-with-springs-formselect-tag/#comment-1143  there has been a need to map JSP <form:select path> to the id of the object since spring 3.  ...strange that I can not get my old editors or the suggested formatters to be called....